# Permission problem of .egg of easy_install under windows7/vista

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, easy-install

I use the easy_install to install python packages in a virtuaenv under windows7.  Due to the UAV, I have to run the CMD as administrator for installing packages.  Here comes the problem,  I notice that I can't import the package from a normal user account.

```
>>> import tempita
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tempita
```

But tempita-0.4-py2.6 is just right there in the site-package.  Also, run python as administrator, import works correctly.  That's the problem of permission.  It's strange, I don't know why, but only .egg files are installed with restricted permissions setting.  I find there is an article about this problem:

[easy_install no longer easy on Vista](http://catherinedevlin.blogspot.com/2009/09/easyinstall-no-longer-easy-on-vista.html)

It doesn't work to change the owner or permissions of parent folder, the only solution I know is to modify the permissions of those egg files one by one.  This is really annoying,  why easy_install set such a restricted permissions only to .egg files rather than .py files?  And how can I solve this problem without shut UAV down or run as a super user?

Comment: You can mark all egg files and change permissions to all of them at once.

Comment: I can't find any authorization options with a group multi-selected files.  Maybe windows7 just doesn't support change AAA options to multi-files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started using [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) in lieu of setuptools, because the distribute team has been much more proactive in tracking down problems. Curiously, it appears as if distribute no longer creates zip eggs on my Windows 7 system, perhaps for the permissions issues you've encountered. Switching to distribute might be a solution for you, although I would understand if that seems like more of a hack than a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use ICACLS to reset the file permissions.

```
ICACLS c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\*.egg /reset
```

I suggest trying it with one file first before doing `*.egg`. Note that `*.egg` will likely match egg folders as well.